# Similar content on multiple pages -- Jasper report

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, ireport

My boss is killing me with the 'awesome' idea to generate Jasper report. As long as I am still alive, I have to ask experts here about how to make it happen.

The original requirement is to generate a pdf report with text and form(tables) in one page. I did it.

But the new requirement ask for a new report which contains four pages and each one contains the previous one page content, with only one change(insert different text on every page).

I did some research and didn't find a easy way to do it. So hope everyone on SO can give me a hint. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you hide and show columns based on expression? For example, map fields over fields in your template to account for all 4 pages, and for a given field only show data when PAGE_NUMBER = x or COLUMN_NUMBER = x.

In your query, you could create a constant to identify the page where each row of data should be printed and group on that constant.

Or -- 4 detail bands, and each is set to print only on the appropriate page.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback and thank you for the response. Could you please inform how to actually make a "second" page in iReport? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Subarule - you can't actually make a second page in iReport, but if you know that your output is going to occur over multiple pages, you can set certain columns and fields to print based on that information.

Comment: In your template, you could layer fields on top of fields but set certain fields to only print when PAGE_NUMBER = x.
In this scenario, I think you'd have to structure your query so that you have output for each page (union 4 queries together) or find a way to call the report 4 times (I don't know how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

If its the same text, then add the Text in String objects,
then you can use the same report, with different data-objects, which store the Strings for the text

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback. I am a little confused, even there are four pages, but are they still in one jasper report template? If so, then how we pass all the 4 copies of parameters and fields to the same jasper template?

Comment: i thought if you have the same graphics and style, but only different Text, you can call your Report 4 times. And each time you give your dataobject other values for the text.

Comment: actually I have a bunch of parameters(about 20) pass to the single jasper template, let alone the data source. So do you think I should pass the model who hold all parameters to the template four times? Plus, how to create a template of 4 page on iReport?. Thx in advance.